Getting Internal Error code: 13 when running a task in Google Earth Engine
Getting

Internal Error (Error code:13)

while trying to extract point data for specific locations in from a dataset in Google Earth Engine via the Code Editor. Can someone help?
// Define the coordinates (latitude, longitude)
var coordinates = [
    [13.08, 80.27],
    [22.57, 88.36],
    [26.14, 91.73],
    [17.4, 78.47],
    [14.47, 78.8],
    [12.97, 77.65],
    [23.73, 69.85],
    [19.99, 73.78,],
    [26.91, 75.78],
    [24.17, 85.88],
    [26.8, 80.9],
    [13.32, 77.47]
];

// Define the variables to extract
var variables = [
  'particulate_matter_d_less_than_25_um_surface',
  'particulate_matter_d_less_than_10_um_surface',
  'total_column_nitrogen_dioxide_surface',
  'total_column_sulphur_dioxide_surface',
  'total_column_carbon_monoxide_surface'
];

// Define the time range
var startDate = '2023-01-01';
var endDate = '2023-12-31';

// Function to extract data for a given variable and coordinates
function extractData(variable, coords) {
  var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/CAMS/NRT')
                .select(variable)
                .filterDate(startDate, endDate);
  
  var data = coords.map(function(coord) {
    var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coord[1], coord[0]);
    var value = dataset.mean().reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: point,
      scale: 10000,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    }).get(variable);
    return ee.Number(value);
  });
  
  return data;
}

// Extract data for each variable
var data = {};
variables.forEach(function(variable) {
  data[variable] = extractData(variable, coordinates);
});

// Print the data to the console
print('Extracted Data:', data);

// Prepare data for CSV export
var features = [];
coordinates.forEach(function(coord, index) {
  var properties = {};
  variables.forEach(function(variable) {
    properties[variable] = data[variable][index];
  });
  properties['latitude'] = coord[0];
  properties['longitude'] = coord[1];
  features.push(ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(coord[1], coord[0]), properties));
});

// Export the data to CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection(features),
  description: 'cams_data_2023',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});


You may want to edit the question to show that the error is in the dataset 'ECMWF/CAMS/NRT'

While your code is unnecessarily convoluted, the issue is actually from a corrupted image in the dataset
First: Isolate the source of error in the dataset and find the corrupted image
I tried to filter for several date ranges to zero in the source of error then find the index of the corrupted image. See the code here
Second: Filter to exclude the corrupted image using the index from 1.:  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', '20230512T00F000').not())
Third: Simplify the code to do the job by making a ee.FeatureCollection form the points coordinates and then using .reduceRegions() on the reduced mean dataset instead of several unnecessary iteration
See the revised code here
